# Identifying symbols in an image iOS

Tags: ios, uiimage

I'm trying to build a functionality where I need to detect different symbols in an image, click on each one of them separately and send a request to the server asking for information of that symbol. Identification of the symbols will be done at the backend.

I was referring the following link: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/detecting_objects_in_still_images 
Will the approach mentioned in the link work for this application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is kinda broad.

But overall - yeah, the method will work for your case.

You need individual characters, not just block of text. So, take a close look at [characterBoxes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/vntextobservation/2867213-characterboxes).